# Perform Rankover function in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an requirement. when the function is called, it needs to generate relevant SQL query based on the input passed.

**Rank(arg1,arg2)**

**arg1** - numeric field to perform ranking

**arg2** - name of the field to perform rank against

**Rank function definition** - Rank all rows based on a field value, ordered by a distinct parent field value.

I am not clear on this. anyone came across this kind of requirements?

I have tried

`SELECT Salary, RANK() OVER( ORDER BY Salary ASC) FROM Person`

But not sure where to use and how to use the second arg2.

Thanks

Comment: Do you not just need `ORDER BY Salary, ParentField`? Also `RANK` is a function, and so needs parenthesis after it: `RANK()`, not `RANK`.

Comment: @Larnu -Thanks for your response. I have tried ORDER BY Salary, Gender but it is not working.

Comment: What does "not working" mean?

Comment: I think what you want is `RANK() OVER( PARTITION BY ParentField ORDER BY Salary ASC)`

Comment: It is not giving desired output. In old system, when the rank function is called, it is giving some output, which is not matching with the query results.  SELECT Salary, RANK() OVER( ORDER BY Salary, GENDER ) FROM Person.

Comment: @Dordi -Thanks for your inputs. It is working RANK() OVER( PARTITION BY ParentField ORDER BY Salary ASC)